# how to plot image in 3d graph matplotlib

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, 3d

I have a cylinder in my matplotlib. I want to be able to put small 2d pictures of mixing blades inside. They can remain in 2d, but the graph and the cylinder are 3d. How do I go about doing this? I can't seem to find anything online about this. Code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as img
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Scatter graph
N = 100
X = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, N)
Y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, N)
Z = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, N)
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z)

# Cylinder
x=np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
z=np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
Xc, Zc=np.meshgrid(x, z)
Yc = np.sqrt(1-Xc**2)

# Draw parameters
rstride = 20
cstride = 10
ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yc, Zc, alpha=0.2, rstride=rstride, cstride=cstride)
ax.plot_surface(Xc, -Yc, Zc, alpha=0.2, rstride=rstride, cstride=cstride)


image_name='download.jpeg'
im_data = img.imread(image_name)
print(im_data)
print(np.shape(im_data))
cmap = 'jet'
ax.imshow(im_data, interpolation='nearest')




ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")
ax.set_zlabel("Z")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Where are the images? How should they appear in the plot?

Comment: I think the image is here `ax.imshow(im_data, interpolation='nearest')`

Comment: The image is download.jpeg, I don't know how to make it appear in a 3d graph, I am really new to matplotlib

Comment: The goal is to simulate a mixer. Basically there should be a round cylinder, and then download.jpeg will be the image of a mixing blade, which can be a 2d image in the 3d graph. I just don't know how to do that.

Comment: Like for example, I want the picture to be put in the 3d space with vertices at 0,0; 0,1; 1,1; 1,0; and it can be flat I just have no idea how to do that

Comment: In a more clear concise way, how to map a 2d image onto a 3d plot. The 2d image can still be completely flat, but you should be able to position it where you want?